# If $\dim (ker A) +\dim (im A) = n$ is equivalent to non-singularity?

Tags: linear-algebra

I consider if $\dim (ker A) +\dim (im A) = n$ is equivalent to non-singularity of $A$ ?  For me,  I can't check it.
It is easy to see that
If $A$ is nonsingular then $\dim(ker A)= \dim(\{0\})=0 $ and $\dim(im A)=n$.
However, in reverse side... I have no idea.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: You didn't say what $A$ was, nor what $n$ was, but I'll guess $A$ is a square matrix of size $n$. Did you check the case $A=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
You can see $\det A=0$, so it is singular, but $\dim(\ker A)=\dim(\text{im}A)=1$; these add up to $n=2$, so the two are in fact not equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that

$\dim(\mbox{im}(A))+\dim(\ker(A))=n$

for **any** (singular or not) linear transformation $A$ on a vector space of dimension $n$ is a very important theorem in linear algebra, known as the **rank-nullity theorem**. You can se a  proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem#Proofs).